# How to pass URL as a variable in <object> data?

Tags: javascript, html

Inside my JavaScript I have the following variable:

```
url = A + 'abc/' + B + '.test';
```

A & B are the variables. when I am doing `alert(url);` I am getting the correct URL. I want to pass this url variable in the object.

```
<object style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="(URL as variable)"></object>
```

1. How should I pass the URL as variable?
2. Is it possible to call javaScript function on `data="someFun()"` ?

   ```
   function someFun(){
      url = A + 'abc/' + D + '.test';
   }
   ```

and then

```
<object style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="someFun()"></object>
```

3. If yes, which approach is better passing variable or calling a function in case of URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript cannot get executed inside `data=`. So you might need to use:

```
element.setAttribute("data", url);
```

After the `url` variable is declared.

To call a function on `data="someFun()"`, you need to select using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data="someFun()"]')[0];
```

Comment: There is no way to pass javascript variable inside the data="<variable>" correct ? I am using object to append/load the result of url in the div like :  $("#result").html('<object style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="url"></object>');

Comment: Do that `data="' + url + '"></object>'` way!